# Is there a way to force-invoke the overridden method?

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, virtual

The code scenario is as follows:

```
class ParentClass {
    void foo();
    virtual void doSomething() { foo(); }
};

class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
    virtual void doSomething();
};
```

Now, is there a way to force the child class to call the parent class' doSomething()? Let's assume that calling `foo()` is vital and should always be called when `doSomething()` is called. The child class can of course call `ParentClass::doSomething()`, but it seems a bit "risky" as it is not enforced.

I have come up with a "dirty" solution which is something like this:

```
class ParentClass {
    void foo();
    void doSomething() final {foo(); doSomethingChild(); }
    virtual void doSomethingChild() = 0;
};

class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
    virtual void doSomethingChild();
};
```

This way, child classes have to do the implementation and `foo()` is always called, but the method is not the same anymore. Is there any solutions that are more elegant?

Comment: Your "dirty" solution is called the template method pattern. It's a perfectly fine solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the way you're doing it is the way it's done.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt For some reason, it still makes me feel like a sinner though. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a dirty solution, but the non-virtual interface idiom (or template method pattern) that you discovered by yourself.

By defining a non-virtual function that calls a virtual function (among other things), you force every implementation of your class to implement the behavior of the non-virtual. The implementation are only free to modify part of this behavior, that is, the call to the virtual function.

This is usually done like so:

```
class Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        //do stuff
        fooImpl();
        //do other stuff
    }
private:
    virtual void fooImpl(); //pure or not
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    virtual void fooImpl(){
    // Implement or change fooImpl behavior
    }
};
```

Making the non virtual public and the virtual private ensures as well that nobody can call `fooImpl` on these classes, which is what you want as you need some stuff to be perfom before and/or after the call to `fooImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

Let see could this work :

```
class parent {
     void foo() {...}
     virtual void doFinal() {...}
     void doSomething (){foo(); doFinal();}
}

class child {
    virtual void doFinal() {...}
}
```

So you can reimplement doFinal ans use doSmthing.